# React Native setState doesn't effect immediately data

Tags: react-native

I am developing a project with react native.After using axios fetch data , then I changed my billingList state using returning data,but after that when I want logged this state,my array is blank.Data is returning but state doesn't change immediately.

```
 axios.get(url, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.status === true) {
                    console.log(response.data.data);
                    setBillingList(response.data.data)           
                    console.log(billingList);

                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
       
    }
```

So using this data in responsive table,table is blank .

```
import { TableView } from "react-native-responsive-table"


 return (


        <View>
            <TableView
                headers={[
                    {
                        name: "S.no.",
                        reference_key: "no",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Name",
                        reference_key: "name",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Age",
                        reference_key: "age",
                    },
                ]}
                rows={billingList}
            />
        </View>
      

    )
```

Comment: how you send the `billingList` state to table component?

Comment: In TableView part  rows={billingList}

Comment: it different component I think?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: wait, what do you want? api call and setState both are async, couldnt get your request

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your axios request in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url, config)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.status === true) {
                console.log(response.data.data);
                setBillingList(response.data.data)           
                console.log(billingList);

            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
   
}
}, [])
```

I have done this multiple times and it should work!

Comment: You can also do a conditional, checking if the data is fetched by doing a ternary operation with your data state